# Mercurial hg stat incorrectly showing a file as Removed - Why?

Tags: mercurial

Right now I run hg stat and have a big red `R` next to a file that I've verified is actually there.

I got here by: using hg rename, trying to revert to a pre-rename revision (which, by the way, didn't work), and then copying the .orig back to its original filename.

But now I still have the big `R`. I can take care of this by calling `hg revert` on the file and then copying the .orig, but why is this happening in the first place? Could it happen in other situations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lets say you have a file `foo.txt` and you do

```
$ hg rename foo.txt bar.txt
$ hg status
A bar.txt
R foo.txt
```

`foo.txt` is marked as removed (`R`) and the new file `bar.txt` is marked as added (`A`). You tried to revert. But as you said for some reason it failed:

> trying to revert to a pre-rename revision (which, by the way, didn't work)

So nothing has changed. the `foo.txt` is still marked as removed and `bar.txt` is marked as added.

It doesn't matter if you manually revert a file `foo.txt`.

```
$ mv bar.txt foo.txt
$ hg status
R foo.txt
! bar.txt
```

It will just say that the file `bar.txt` that you added with rename is missing.

Mercurial recorded your actions and keeps track of the added and removed files. Manually adding and removing files doesn't help. To fix this you should instruct mercurial to re-add the `foo.txt` and remove `bar.txt`.

```
$ hg add foo.txt
$ hg status
! bar.txt
$ hg remove bar.txt
$ hg status
$
```